# How to get two functions inside Popover

Tags: php, html

Good morning everyone, I am starting a project and would like to show the status of my indirect, I managed to create the function to show all the names of each of them within a popover and created another function that checks if the user is active or inactive but I could not put the two together in the popover, how can I do?
For example, when I click on the image I have the following user name popover:

```
1. Jhonn
2. Star
3. Paul
4. Julie
5. Robert
```

The way I want to be able to do it is this:

```
1. Jhonn   Active
2. Star    Inactive
3. Paul    Active
4. Julie   Inactive
5. Robert  Active
```

Currently the **getStatus** function only returns me 1 value and is getting below other names:

```
1. Jhonn
2. Star
3. Paul
4. Julie
5. Robert
 Active
```

The function I am using to return the names in html are this `{{$ user-> nnIndicateds ()}}`:

```
    public function nnIndicateds() {

       return implode('<li>', User::where('referrer_id', $this->id)->pluck('name')->all());

 }
```

The function to get the result of each active or inactive user is this `{{$user->getStatus()}}`:

```
function getStatus($status = '', $nm = '') {

        if ($status == '') {

            $status = $this->active;

        }

        if ($nm <> '') {

            if ($status == 1) {

                return 'Yes';

            } else {

                return 'No';

            }

        } else {

            if ($status == 1) {

                return 'Active';

            } else {

                return 'Inative';

            }

        }

    }
```

My Html:

```
<img class="img-avatar img-avatar-thumb" data-placement="top" src="uploads/positive.png" width="30" heigth="30" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-original-title="My Indirects" data-content="<ol><li>{{$user->nnIndicateds()}}</li></ol>" data-toggle="popover" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: How about putting you data in a collection (DB) or array?

Comment: I'm a beginner, I don't know how to do

Comment: Sr, I don't understand clearly. Do you want to show a list of users in popover and show "name" and active/inactive status? In Laravel framework: You can create a model User with some properties: `getStatusAttribute()`, so you can display both name : `$user->name` and status: `user->status` (status is alias of getStatusAttribute)

Comment: yes, both functions are already done and functional, but I would like to show the name on the left side and the status on the right side as I did in the 2º example of the post, because the only way I got it was the same as the 3º example

Comment: 1. I did not see you use `getStatus()` in your code. 2. `implode('<li>', ...` and `data-content="<ol><li>...`, you use `<li>` 2 times. 3. `pluck('name')` will return an array, so you cannot get `getStatus()`.

Comment: One solution: `nnIndicateds()` must return an array of 2 dimensions, so you can display name and status in popover. For example: `pluck("name", "status")` (of course, you must process status value already) (I do not know you what js framework you are using to collect result data, and I am not good at frontend, so I cannot advise more.)

Comment: Another solution: In Laravel, `nnIndicateds()`, do not use `pluck`, use `->get()` or `->all()`. you can run foreach loop to get data from User model, then output `$user->name` and `$user->getStatus()`.

Comment: yes, in my code I don't use {{$ user-> getStatus ()}}, as it only fetches 1 user from each query, so I would like to merge it with {{nnIndicateds ()}}

Comment: I see
The fastest way to fix is:
`public function nnIndicateds() {
 $collection = User::where('referrer_id', $this->id)->get();
 foreach($collection as $key => $user){
  $user->status = $this->getStatus();
 }
 return $collection;
}`
It will return a collection and storing all data: name, status, active, etc. In case you want an array, just `$collection->toArray()` in Laravel . Please have a try.

Comment: is returning me all the data of each user, name, email, avatar, id, address, city and it's all within characters for example: [{"id": 7, "name": "Jhonn Nuno Torr \ u00e3o Carmona" , "email": "jhonn@gmail.com", "email_verified_at": "2019-10-01 07:36:44", "created_at": "2019-08-26 04:47:51", "updated_at" : "2019-09-30

Comment: Correct, it returns all data. So in frontend, you can use any data that you want. But update code `getStatus` to correct process. Is there any problem?